# Checking if textarea and input isset

Tags: php, html, forms, textarea, isset

Hello i want to check if the textarea isnt empty and i still can´t get the echo that i want even when the textarea isnt empty and input is set
here is my code:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="jmeno"/>
    <textarea name="textarea" id="textarea" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>


<?php 
if(isset($_POST['jmeno']) AND !empty($_POST['textarea'])){
    echo "dokončeno";
}
?>
```

Comment: It's working. so what's your problem?

Comment: I dont know man.. when i tryied it didnt work .. im sorry

Comment: its working .If you get error post your error too

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand you want your code to check if the submit button is pressed and the textarea isn't empty. I would say the code is:

```
if(isset($_POST['jmeno'])){
    if(strlen($_POST['textarea']) > 0){
        echo "dokončeno";
    }
}
```

OR simply:

```
if(isset($_POST['jmeno']) && strlen($_POST['textarea']) > 0){
    echo "dokončeno";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```php
if (!is_null($_POST['jmeno']) && strlen(trim($_POST['jmeno'])) > 0) {
    echo "dokončeno";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_POST['jmeno']) && strlen(trim($_POST['textarea']))>0)
{
 echo "dokončeno";
}
```